# How do I get XML data from a web service using PHP?

Tags: php, .net, xml, web-services, soap

I need to access the response from a .NET web service which returns data in XML format.
How can I split the data returned? For example, I would like to parse the data into some PHP variables:

```php
$name = "Dupont";
$email = "charles.dupont@societe.com";
```

I have been looking for how to do this for a long time without finding the correct way to do it.

My script is:

```
$result = $client->StudentGetInformation($params_4)->StudentGetInformationResult;

    echo "<p><pre>" . print_r($result, true) . "</pre></p>";
```

The echo in my page is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [any] => 0Successful10371DupontCharlescharles.dupont@societe.com1234charles.dupont@societe.comfalsefr-FR1003FIRST FINANCE1778AAA DÃ©partement
)
```

The webservice response format is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <StudentGetInformationResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <StudentGetInformationResult>xml</StudentGetInformationResult>
    </StudentGetInformationResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

---

I have tried your example. But it doesn't do what i need.
I need to split the value returned. I would like to get the data and put them into PHP variables:

$name = "Dupont";
$email = "charles.dupont@societe.com";
etc...

Unfortunately the echo of your example gives:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["StudentGetInformationResult"]=> object(stdClass)#11 (1) { ["any"]=> string(561) "0Successful10371DupontCharlescharles.dupont@societe.com1234charles.dupont@societe.comfalsefr-FR1003FIRST FINANCE1778AAA DÃ©partement" } }
```

Comment: `SoapClient` http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php works like charm

Comment: Thanks... but do you know which class do i have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only class you need is `SoapClient`. There are a lot of examples you can use in the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php).

Example:

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient ( "some.aspx?wsdl" );
    $result = $client->StudentGetInformation ( $params_4 );

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result->StudentGetInformationResult->any);
    echo "<pre>" ;

    foreach ($xml as $key => $value)
    {
        foreach($value as $ekey => $eValue)
        {
            print($ekey . " = " . $eValue . PHP_EOL);
        }
    }

} catch ( SoapFault $fault ) {
    trigger_error ( "SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR );
}
```

Output

```
Code = 0
Message = Successful
stud_id = 10373
lname = Dupont
fname = Charles
loginid = charles.dupont@societe.com
password = 1234
email = charles.dupont@societe.com
extid = 
fdisable = false
culture = fr-FR
comp_id = 1003
comp_name = FIRST FINANCE
dept_id = 1778
dept_name = Certification CMF (Test web service)
udtf1 = 
udtf2 = 
udtf3 = 
udtf4 = 
udtf5 = 
udtf6 = 
udtf7 = 
udtf8 = 
udtf9 = 
udtf10 = 
Audiences =
```

Comment: i have to wait 7 hours before to use the Answer button!

Comment: I have tried your example. But it doesn't do what i need. I need to split the value returned. I would like to get the data and put them into PHP variables:

$name = "Dupont"; $email = "charles.dupont@societe.com"; etc...

Unfortunately the echo of your example gives:
`code`
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["StudentGetInformationResult"]=> object(stdClass)#11 (1) { ["any"]=> string(561) "0Successful10371DupontCharlescharles.dupont@societe.com1234charles.dupont@societe.comfalsefr-FR1003FIRST FINANCE1778AAA DÃ©partement" } }`code`

Comment: The values is at `$result->StudentGetInformationResult->any`  and the format you are getting `0Successful10371DupontCharlescharles.dupont@societe.com1234charles.dupont@societe.comfalsefr-FR1003FIRST FINANCE1778AAA DÃ©partement` lookas a bit strange .. can you put the wasdl link let me try it myself ??? @emb

Comment: The echo of $result->StudentGetInformationResult->any gives the string: 0Successful10373DupontCharlescharles.dupont@societe.com1234charles.dupont@societe.comfalsefr-FR1003FIRST FINANCE1778Certification CMF. 

I unfortunately cannot give you the wsdl url.
I still look for a way to access each part of data given in this string.

Comment: I would love if this kind of code would work, but it doesn't...:
$result->StudentGetInformationResult->any['email']

Comment: `var_dump($result->StudentGetInformationResult)` and paste the output .. i can figure the rest for you

Comment: The output of `var_dump($result->StudentGetInformationResult)` is again the string: `object(stdClass)#18 (1) { ["any"]=> string(562) "0Successful10373DupontCharlescharles.dupont@societe.com1234charles.dupont@societe.comfalsefr-FR1003FIRST FINANCE1778Certification CMF" } ` I continue to look for the solution in the internet, but without finding it so far. Thanks

Comment: Seen obviously the are sine hidden characters .. after `var_dump($result->StudentGetInformationResult)` now click on `view source` copy the var_dump and paste it in http://pastebin.com/ copy the link here and i"ll look for a solution for you

Comment: In the source i can see (but just see) what i am looking for: the tag of each field (last name, first name, login...). `<lname>Dupont</lname><fname>Charles</fname><loginid>charles.dupont@societe.com</loginid>` The question now still: how can i get them and put in variables?

Comment: Ok .. i see it now .. i would update my code today with the solution .... well done ...